# LabVIEW generated Excel files unable to be read by pandas.read_excel

Tags: python, r, excel, pandas, labview

I'm having an issue when I save LabVIEW outputs as .xlsx files. When I try to import with Pandas I get the following error:

expected <class 'openpyxl.styles.fills.Fill'>

It seems LabVIEW uses unusual encoding or something.

One workaround that I've found is that if I just open the Excel file and save it, there's no problem reading with Pandas. Is there a simple way to automate opening an excel file in Python or R and saving it?

Thanks all!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Perhaps a vba code?

Comment: In R the openxlsx, XLConnect and xlsx packages can read and write Excel files.

Comment: Please show the LabVIEW code that saves the .xlsx files, preferably as a [VI Snippet](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/lvhowto/create_visnippet/). Also if possible please show an example of the data?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,maybe, I can't understand your questions, you seems to whether you can open LabVIEW file and reload it. If I have meet this question, I will use python3 to decode. for example:

```
df = pd.read_excel(f'E:\\每月笔记采集数据文件\\11月笔记采集任务\\{name}')
```

If I have no understand your problems, it's my faults. Thanks for your reading.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is over a year later, but I found a solution after some digging and I wanted to share in case anyone else ran into this issue.  It looks like the LabView program that output the Excel file didn't adhere to the same standard as openpyxl was expecting. An easy workaround for data collection that has already been run is to open the file in Excel and save it as the OP mentioned.

This can be automated using the win32com.client module. After running the code below, openpyxl functions as expected.

```
import win32com.client
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open('LabView_output_file.xlsx')
workbook.Save()
workbook.Close()
excel.Quit()
```

Comment: A year later and I've still just been manually opening and saving haha so thank you!!